# MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument after version update

Tags: nuget

After updating NuGet to version 2.8.50313.31, opening the Package Manager Console displays a number of errors.

Is this a known issue with that (now current) version?  Is there a fix/work-around?

If there is no fix, how does one revert to the previous version of NuGet?

> New-Object : Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Management.Automation, Ver sion=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its d ependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :143 char:27
>   +     $newProvider = New-Object <<<<  $powerShellScaffolderProviderType($mvcSca ffoldingProvider)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundExce     ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerS
>   hell.Commands.NewObjectCommand   Cannot convert argument "0", with
>   value: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffo
>   lding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffolderProvider", for "Add" to type
>   "Microsoft.Vi
>   sualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider":
>   "Cannot conve rt the
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffol
>   derProvider" value of type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShe
>   ll.PowerShellScaffolderProvider" to type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extens
>   ibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider"." At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :144 char:19
>   +     $allProviders.Add <<<< ($newProvider) | Out-Null
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument   PM> New-Object : Could
>   not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Ver
>   sion=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one
>   of its d ependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :143 char:27
>   +     $newProvider = New-Object <<<<  $powerShellScaffolderProviderType($mvcSca ffoldingProvider)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundExce     ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerS
>   hell.Commands.NewObjectCommand   Cannot convert argument "0", with
>   value: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffo
>   lding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffolderProvider", for "Add" to type
>   "Microsoft.Vi
>   sualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider":
>   "Cannot conve rt the
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffol
>   derProvider" value of type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShe
>   ll.PowerShellScaffolderProvider" to type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extens
>   ibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider"." At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :144 char:19
>   +     $allProviders.Add <<<< ($newProvider) | Out-Null
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument   New-Object : Could not
>   load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Ver sion=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its d
>   ependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :143 char:27
>   +     $newProvider = New-Object <<<<  $powerShellScaffolderProviderType($mvcSca ffoldingProvider)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], FileNotFoundExce     ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerS
>   hell.Commands.NewObjectCommand   Cannot convert argument "0", with
>   value: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffo
>   lding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffolderProvider", for "Add" to type
>   "Microsoft.Vi
>   sualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extensibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider":
>   "Cannot conve rt the
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShell.PowerShellScaffol
>   derProvider" value of type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.PowerShe
>   ll.PowerShellScaffolderProvider" to type
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Extens
>   ibility.Scaffolding.ScaffolderProvider"." At
>   E:\dev\myProject\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.0.6\tools\registerWithMvcTooling.ps1
>   :144 char:19
>   +     $allProviders.Add <<<< ($newProvider) | Out-Null
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `MvcScaffolding.1.0.6` is no longer referenced by any project in the solution.

Removing it from the NuGet command line

```
Uninstall-Package MvcScaffolding
```

resolved the issue.

There is currently version 1.0.9 of MvcScaffolding.  The issue may be resolved in that version.  However, since I no longer reference that package, I did not test that.